# why my html5 video begins from start whenever i try to forward it for few seconds?

Tags: html, video

I am using a laravel project and i have implemented a html5 video tag. Video starts streaming whenever i click on play button but the problem is whenever i try to forward the video player for some duration then video automatically starts from beginning.

I have also disabled all javascript and css files attached but still same problem exists and there is nothing wrong with the video as this problem does not appear on other PHP projects when i use the same video..

```
<video controls width="100%">
<source src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/elearning/3/tutorial/62a0df6b1c38d.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Well PHP is not doing anything in the process of trying to fast forward in the video, it is all going on in the browser

Comment: Wild speculation: Your HTTP server does not support `Content-Range` and the browser is using it to seek.

Comment: Try removing the `:8000` part of your URL. See if it can seek now.

Comment: i have tried to run the same video in a core PHP project and it is working fine but not in a laravel project. I am using chrome browser and what should i do to get rid of this probelm if http server does not support content-range....